# Get data from mysql depending on what the user has done

Tags: php, mysql

This is a bit of a brain teaser and I have been trying to think of how to do it for a while. Not sure if the title gives away enough but it's the best i could do.

I have a centralized audio playing system in a site that I am developing at the moment. By centralized I mean everything on the site plays through it, so only one track can be playing at once and it will also make continuous play doable.

Before I go into detail about the players I should explain parts of the site. The site hosts music and other things for musicians. The musicians are voted in to be on the site by users. To vote a user will click vote, listen to the track and click like or dislike, simple! Once the track has enough likes the track's creator will become part of the site and will be able to upload more tracks to there profile as well as other things. That should explain what this part of the site is about so I can go into detail about the players.

There are 2 players, one in the toolbar and an in page one which there can be several of, kind of like soundcloud's players. Everything is linked together so if a track is played on an inpage player it is played in the toolbar player and vice versa.

The audio players are built with jQuery.

There are also 3 things the user can do to trigger audio play;

1. Play the newest track which is shown in the toolbar player.
2. Play a track in the in page player.
3. Click vote and listen to a random track to vote on.

Now the problem I am having is with the mysql queries and how they are selected. Because each of the 3 triggers the user can send need different mysql queries I need to think of a way to select the query for each trigger.

In the queries below I have left out variables and the queries that get the information about the artist based on the track selected.

Query for 1 (toolbar player);

```
$fetchtrack = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracks ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1");
$track = mysql_fetch_array($fetchurl);

$url = $track['url'];
```

Query for 2 (in page player)

```
$fetchtrack = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE track_ID = Variable for the selected track");
$track = mysql_fetch_array($fetchurl);

$url = $track['url'];
```

Query for 3 (vote)

```
 //Set up artist query so no artists are shown and cannot be voted on

 $findartist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artists");
 $artist = mysql_fetch_array($findartist);

 $artist =  $artist['name']; 

 //Set up vote query so that you are not shown a track you have already voted on

 $findvoted = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM votes WHERE ID = '$user_ID'");
 $voted = mysql_fetch_array($findvoted);

 $votedID = $voted['track_ID'];

 //Query tracks with relevent information

 $fetchtrack = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE ID != '$user_ID' AND track_ID != '$votedID' LIMIT 1");
 $track = mysql_fetch_array($fetchtrack);
 $url = $track['url'];
```

Oh and just so it helps you get the picture the voting system, toolbar player and in page player are all in separate files and all link to a single js file for the jQuery. The $url variable is put into the jQuery as a var.

How would I select the right query for the right thing to happen? Or at least select the right outcome of the queries?

I am sorry the question is a bit long winded but I needed to explain almost every detail.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Do you mean using a `$_GET` variable, or calling different pages?

Comment: Yes I know and I am working on changing over but I have a few other people working on this project and we all need to learn them.

Comment: @arxanasI A get variable wouldn't work. All the different playing triggers are on the same page.

Comment: Make an AJAX call with a `$_GET` parameter called something like `source` which refers to one of your javascript players. Seems simple.

Comment: @CodyCaughlan All the players run through the same javascript file so would need to change the parameter for each query

Comment: @CodyCaughlan I understand useing a $_GET parameter in jQuery would be the way to go but how can I determine which query to use? I am using AJAX in jQUery anyway

Comment: You need to somehow give metadata to your Javascript so it knows which query to invoke, which is then passed via ajax/_GET. Each of your player is in a DIV or something, right? If so, then add a customer `data-source` attribute, like `data-source=header-player` which you can then read in the player JS and pass that along to your ajax call, which is ultimately used to determine which query to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted it. I have ended up using several AJAX requests in my javascript so it is pretty long winded. There is an AJAX request for each query and each query is in a separate file with the url being echoed out. The url is then sent back to the javascript which plays the song. At the same time the url is sent to one of the players where yet more sql queries are maded and the right info is retrieved and echoed for the right track. It was simple and logical when i got the hang of AJAX function in jQuery.